# How can I "download" the content of a GitHub workplace I'm in?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to GitHub, in fact, I just created an account and been added to my workplace group, not sure what the correct term is but how can I "download" the content of branches and directories to adjust the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git clone <ssh_repo_url>
```

OR

```
git clone <http_repo_url>
```

Try go through this quick interactive git tutorial to get familiarized with it

https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Comment: i tried the following: git cd path_to_location then git clone https://..... and got the error fatal repository not found.

Comment: Looks like a private one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get you right but you probably mean that you created a "Repository" not a "Workspace".
Instead of downloading and than reuploading the entire project, you are doing a `git clone`.
Simply open up a terminal on your local machine and type `git clone <GIT_URL>`.
Than you can perform all your regular git commands like `git add` `git commit` …
If you like to push your code back to GitHub you simply perform a `git push`.
For your understanding: GitHub is *just* a platform to host your Git repository.

Comment: i  tried the following: git cd path_to_location then git clone https://..... and got the error fatal repository not found.